# Modern SharePoint Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

WE currently have a private team site and want to publish news to a public communication site. The communication site is a Hub and the team site is a member of the hub. My understanding is that if the news item is created in the private team site, it retains the private permissions on the Team site even in the Hub. is that right?

We need each news item when it gets to the HUB to be accessed by everyone (readable only). Any way to achieve? Just make the SitePages library read only for everyone on the private team site?

Thank you
Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can just share the site pages library with “everyone except external users” with “can view” permission, or share the relevant news items with everyone. Then other users will view the news from private team site in communication hub site.

[image]